# Python subprocess: Ack does not work

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
check_call('ack "foo" /path/to/Documents/filename.txt', shell=True, stdout=f)
```

within a python jupyter notebook but get an error back

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'ack "foo" /path/to/Documents/filename.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you mean awk? ...

Comment: The output of `stderr` should give you some useful information.

Comment: @YOU: `awk "foo"` doesn't make much sense, but `ack "foo"` does.  `ack` is like `grep`.

Comment: Thx @DietrichEpp. for that case if you have "ack" in your distro, you may have space in your /path/to/, try double quoting it.

Comment: ... or get rid of `shell=True` and use `check_call(["ack", "foo", "/path/to/Documents/filename.txt"], stdout=f)`. exit status 1 means [no match found](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ack) for ack